# How can I merge three html elements

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following structure:

```html
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<span>dolor</span>
<p>sit amen</p>
```

What is the best way to programmatically get the following in JS?

```html
<p>lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amen</p>
```

Is it possible also to do this with differents tags like

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
<span>dolor</span>
<h1>sit amen</h1>
```

That should result in

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amen</h1>
```

I'm not talking just of three elements: could be also something like:

```
p
span
p
span
p
```

Comment: Are you talking about merging programatically with JS? If not, this feels like an odd question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I update the question

Comment: Is it always three elements? Are they always on new lines? Should they all be wrapped in the tag that appears first?

Comment: You could append the span to the first paragraph, and then append the text node from the second paragraph to the first. But you will still need to explicitly add the spaces you want before and after the span, so either create new text nodes and append them, or manipulate the text content of the paragraphs beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution can use in any number of elements, the elements will be merged with the `tag` of the first element, in case the element have the same tag of the first element, it will be merged with it's `textContent` if not it will be appended with it's tag.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const [first, ...rest] = container.children;
const result = rest.reduce((acc, child) => {
  if (child.tagName === first.tagName) {
    first.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' +
    child.textContent));
  } else {
    first.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
    first.appendChild(child);
  }
  return acc;
}, first)


container.innerHTML = ''
container.appendChild(result)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <h1>sit amen</h1>
  <span>dolor2</span>
  <h1>sit amen2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
const h1tag = document.createElement("h1");
const node = document.createTextNode( 
    document.querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerHTML + " " + 
    document.querySelector("span").outerHTML + " " + 
    document.querySelectorAll("h1")[1].innerHTML  
    );
h1tag.appendChild(node);
```

Comment: This doesn't check the span is between the `<h1>`'s (or that there are no other elements between them). It would only work for one specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
const inPnl = document.getElementById('input');
const elems = inPnl.querySelectorAll('p, span');
const outPnl = document.getElementById('output');

elems[0]
  .appendChild(elems[1])
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(elems[2].innerText));

outPnl.appendChild(elems[0]);
```

```html
<em>input:</em>
<div id=input>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<span>dolor</span>
<p>sit amen</p>
</div>

<em>output:</em>
<div id=output>
</div>
```

Replace p with h1 in query selector, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So as it might be `<p>` or `<h1>` tags or something I assume you can add containers around the elements that need to be restructured. If so, you could do something generic like this.

```js
function restructure()
{
  // get all divs that needs to be restructured
  let divsToRestructure = document.querySelectorAll('.default-structure');

  divsToRestructure.forEach(divToRestructure => {
      // do what needs to happen to restructure a div
      let elements = divToRestructure.querySelectorAll('*');
      let parentTag = elements[0].tagName;

      // create the element that needs to contain the new structure
      let newStructure = document.createElement(parentTag);

      // add all old elements in the new structure
      elements.forEach(element => {
        if(element.tagName == parentTag){
          newStructure.innerHTML += element.innerHTML;
        } else{
          newStructure.innerHTML += element.outerHTML;
        }
        newStructure.innerHTML += ' ';
    })
    
    
    // clear the default-structured div
    divToRestructure.innerHTML = '';
    // add the new structure to the div
    divToRestructure.appendChild(newStructure);
    divToRestructure.classList.remove('default-structure');
    divToRestructure.classList.add('new-structure');
  });
}
```

```css
div { border: solid black 1px; }
span { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<button onclick="restructure()">Restructure</button>

<div class="default-structure">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <p>sit amen</p>
</div>

<div class="default-structure">
  <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <h1>sit amen</h1>
</div>

<div class="default-structure">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <p>sit amen</p>
  <span>consectetur</span>
  <p>adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```